# can not use watin

Tags: c#, watin, missing-features

I run a very simple watin console application like below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using WatiN.Core;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IE ie = new IE();

            // point it to http://www.google.com

            ie.GoTo("http://www.google.com");

            // fill the search box

            ie.TextField(Find.ByName("q")).TypeText("WatiN");

            // performs click event

            ie.Button(Find.ByValue("Google Search")).Click();
        }
    }
}
```

Which is not working. A pop up said that there's a missing `.exe` file. I can not understand because it's just a console application. Why do I need the `.exe` file?

Comment: "visual studio can not start debugging because the debug target D:\....\consoleapplication1.exe is missing. Please build the project and retry or set the output path and AssemblyName properties appropriately to point at correct location for the target assembly"

Comment: thanks so much, it work after  i change target .net framework from 4.0 to 3.5. It's really miracle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to use `WatiN` for *web application testing* through *Internet Explorer*, ensure to complete the right configurations first.

`NUnit` doesn't run tests in a thread using the `STA apartment state`; it uses `multithreaded apartment (MTA)`, but this isn't a big problem, you can attach config file to the `NUnit` test project and specify the apartment state mode that you want this way:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="NUnit">
            <section name="TestRunner" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler"/>
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <NUnit>
        <TestRunner>
            <!-- Valid values are STA, MTA. Others ignored. -->
            <add key="ApartmentState" value="STA" />
        </TestRunner>
    </NUnit>
</configuration>
```

Article Reference:

[WatiN, Internet Explorer and Thread.Apartmentstate](http://watin.org/documentation/sta-apartmentstate/)

> This article explains the why and how about setting the ApartmentState of a Thread to single treaded apartment (STA). This is required when running your test with Internet Explorer. It also shows you how to do this when using WatiN with NUnit, MBUnit, MSTest, TestDriven.Net, Fitnesse or SharpDevelop.

Comment: Please refer to this documentation, http://watin.org/documentation/ and http://watin.org/documentation/sta-apartmentstate/

Comment: This link now contains adware. Please don't click it.